# Problems with c# zxing port

Tags: c#, zxing

first excuse me for the bad english, then i wanna ask you a piece of advice to solve this problem. I'm trying to use zxing C# port.

I tried then to parse this image:

[bar code http://img168.imageshack.us/img168/2633/0003gby.jpg](http://img168.imageshack.us/img168/2633/0003gby.jpg)

at zxing.org which recognized it.

The little program I wrote, instead produced a ReaderException.

Any ideas, or anybody who wrote a piece of code which does the job?

Comment: Can you post a stack trace? Can you post the code where the exception is produced?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a bit old, but I've just tried using ZXing's C# port for the first time, and I've found that I have to use the TRY_HARDER DecodeHintType to get the barcode to read.

In the code, it looks like it's expecting the image provided to be a region around the barcode itself, so it starts looking in the middle.  Setting the TRY_HARDER flag makes it search the entire page.